# Xcode AVPlayer crash iPhone 5 - Titanium iOS Module

Tags: objective-c, iphone, titanium, titanium-modules

i have written an Titanium iOS Module for streaming audio.
On iPhone 5s and above the app and the module is running great.

The problem is every time the stopStream function is called in my app on an iPhone 5 or lower the app crashes.

I think there is a memory leak or something but i doesnt find the solution for that problem.

Here is my module code:

//THIS FUNCTION THET STARTS THE STREAM. THERE IS NO PROBLEM ON THE IPHONE 5

```
-(id)startStream:(id)args
{
    ENSURE_SINGLE_ARG(args,NSString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:args];

    playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    player = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [player play];

    [self fireEvent:@"START" withObject:nil];

    NSLog(@"[INFO] player item error : %@", playerItem.error.description);
    NSLog(@"[INFO] player error : %@", player.error.description);

    return args;
}
```

//THIS IS THE FUNCTION WHERE MY APP CRASH ON IPHONE 5

```
-(id)stopStream:(id)args
{
     NSLog(@"[INFO]AVPlayer STOP");
    [player pause];
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" context:nil];
    [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];

    player=nil;
}
```

Here an part of the device log.

```
296 00:43:40 W TestApp[3487] <Warning>: [INFO]AVPlayer STOP 
297 00:43:40 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07,    400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument) 
301 00:43:40 W mediaserverd[37] <Warning>: 00:43:40.969 [0x3257000] CMSession retain count > 1! 
306 00:43:41 W SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application. 
307 00:43:41 W SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application. 
308 00:43:41 W SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 3483: No such process 
309 00:43:41 W SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 3487: No such process 
310 00:43:41 W SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 3487: No such process 
311 00:43:41 W SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 3487: No such process 
312 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs. 
313 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Could not save crash report to disk! 
314 00:43:41 W SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.fpmsoft.isa.TestApp[0x476c]' crashed. 
315 00:43:41 W assertiond[58] <Warning>: pid_suspend failed for <BKNewProcess: 0x14d90e90; com.fpmsoft.isa.TestApp; pid: 3487; hostpid: -1>: Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1 
316 00:43:41 W assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x14d90e90; com.fpmsoft.isa.TestApp; pid: 3487; hostpid: -1> to 2, priority: No such process 
317 00:43:41 W assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x14d90e90; com.fpmsoft.isa.TestApp; pid: 3487; hostpid: -1> to 4096, priority: No such process 
318 00:43:41 W UserEventAgent[17] <Warning>: id=com.fpmsoft.isa.TestApp pid=3487, state=0 
319 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Incident Identifier: 5CF594F7-3628-4EAE-88D6-B6AA4DC4C028 
320 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: CrashReporter Key:   509d7f4d78bbd031f5bf1a6ef122f14f5be24f8b 
321 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2 
322 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Process:             TestApp [3487] 
323 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/78A7A4DB-3377-4875-B86F-217F1B8DFF9E/TestApp.app/TestApp 
324 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Identifier:          TestApp 
325 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Version:             ??? 
326 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Code Type:           ARM (Native) 
327 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Parent Process:      launchd [1] 
328 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Date/Time:           2015-09-13 00:43:40.855 +0200 
329 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Launch Time:         2015-09-13 00:43:34.825 +0200 
330 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70) 
331 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Report Version:      105 
332 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) 
333 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x9805ac14 
334 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Triggered by Thread:  6 
335 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
336 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Thread 0: 
337 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x359b1474 0x359b0000 + 5236 
338 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x359b1268 0x359b0000 + 4712 
339 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 2   CoreFoundation                 0x2708256e 0x26fb5000 + 841070 
340 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 3   CoreFoundation                 0x27080b14 0x26fb5000 + 834324 
341 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 4   CoreFoundation                 0x26fcd1fc 0x26fb5000 + 98812 
342 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 5   CoreFoundation                 0x26fcd00e 0x26fb5000 + 98318 
343 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 6   GraphicsServices               0x2e8ac1fc 0x2e8a3000 + 37372 
344 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 7   UIKit                          0x2a771a54 0x2a702000 + 457300 
345 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 8   TestApp                         0x00024ca2 0x20000 + 19618 
346 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 9   libdyld.dylib                  0x358faaac 0x358f9000 + 6828 
347 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 
348 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Thread 1: 
349 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x359b1224 0x359b0000 + 4644 
350 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x358e60ec 0x358d8000 + 57580 
351 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x358dad36 0x358d8000 + 11574 
352 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.appcelerator.anlaytics.databaseQueue 
353 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: Thread 2: 
354 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x359b14c4 0x359b0000 + 5316 
355 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x358e45da 0x358d8000 + 50650 
356 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 2   CFNetwork                      0x26b50c6c 0x26aef000 + 400492 
357 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 3   CFNetwork                      0x26b6bd3a 0x26aef000 + 511290 
358 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 4   TestApp                         0x00374bbc 0x20000 + 3492796 
359 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 5   TestApp                         0x0036c1d2 0x20000 + 3457490 
360 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 6   libdispatch.dylib              0x358e0a38 0x358d8000 + 35384 
361 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 7   TestApp                         0x0036bdaa 0x20000 + 3456426 
362 00:43:41 E ReportCrash[3490] <Error>: 8   libdispatch.dylib              0x358d92cc 0x358d8000 + 4812
```

Comment: When ever you post a question about a crash you must provide details about the crash. What's the complete and exact error message and which line exactly is causing the crash?

Comment: That ist the my big problem. In every Simulator the app runs without problems. Only on the real iPhone 5 device the app crashes. 

And at the moment i cant test it on an real iPhone 5 that i can connect to my Mac. I can only let other people test the app when i build it or test it here testobject.com.

Thats why i have no logs or error messages

Comment: You can get crash reports from test users. They need to sync their device to their computer using iTunes. Then the crash reports will be on their computer.

Comment: I am looking for a similar feature. Do you have the Titanium Module which can be shared as well?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for my problem.
i must add an return in the function.
Now it is working for iPhone5 and lower

```
-(id)stopStream:(id)args
{
     NSLog(@"[INFO]AVPlayer STOP");
    [player pause];

    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" context:nil];
    [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];

    return args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're also over retaining the player. You should `[player release];` in your `stopStream`, or in `startStream`, only instantiate a new `player` if one does not already exist.